# Running dispatchGesture fluidly

Tags: java, android, gesture, accessibilityservice

I'm getting started with android accessibility services and i have to replay a constant gesture above other apps.. On this purpose i'm using the [dispatchGesture()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#dispatchGesture(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) function and all works properly.. I just have problems in terms of graphics because my objective is to reproduce the gesture more fluidly than my actual result.. This is my current code snippet:

```
Builder builder = new Builder();
Path path = new Path();

float r = 200;

path.arcTo(new RectF(initX - r/2, initY, initX + r/2, initY+r),180, 180);
path.arcTo(new RectF(initX - r/2, initY, initX + r/2, initY+r),0, 180);
path.arcTo(new RectF(initX - r/2, initY, initX + r/2, initY+r),180, 180);
path.arcTo(new RectF(initX - r, initY, initX + r/2, initY+r),0, 180);
path.lineTo(initX - r/2 + 50, initY - 200);

builder.addStroke(new StrokeDescription(path, 0, 500));

final GestureDescription build = builder.build();

dispatchGesture(build, new GestureResultCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
        super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
        super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
    }
}, null);
```

My result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGv9H.gif), and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aULa.gif) is what i want. Some tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Try increase `duration`.

Comment: I tryied to adjust the duration parameter but my gesture still be laggy

Answer (score 0):

The points of the gesture are sampled every 100ms. So your 500ms long stroke will have 6 point on it. If you slow down the stroke, you'll get better fidelity with your shape.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i dont need better fidelity i need my gesture to be fluid.